# Excel 12.0 Object Library speed

Tags: c#, excel

I'm writing a C# program that outputs thousands of lines into an excel spreadsheet using the Excel 12.0 Object Library. I noticed that it was generally pretty slow, so I timed it with the Stopwatch class and found out each write to a cell was taking around 4 million ticks.

1. Is this speed normal?
2. Is there a faster alternative?

Edit: 4 not 100 million

Comment: My prior experience has shown this method to be painfully slow.

is this just raw data? Is outputting as a CSV an option?

Comment: This may be a stab in the dark, but I have found if you are forcing any sort of specific font or style, it can slow things down significantly.

Comment: The only formatting I'm doing is changing the number formatting to text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this speed is normal - it is painfully slow.

There are faster alternatives available. I have used SpreadsheetGear, which I found easy to use and much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at the question. [Create excel xls and xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c) a lot of people liked the [Epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library. I just started with it and it seems good.